# For all x, there exist a y such that 2x-y=0 in the set of non negative integers.

Tags: quantifiers

I have the following proposition in the domain of **nonnegative integers**:

$$ \forall x \exists y \cdot(2x-y = 0) $$

I translate it as the following: For all $x \in \{0, 1,  2,3,.... \}$, there is always a $y$ to be found, such that $y=2x$. The answer given is **True**, but I do not understand how this will be true for the case when $x=0$.

Am I correct in assuming that in predicate statements like this, $x$ and $y$ have to be different?

Comment: You are incorrect. We can have $y=x$ without any problem.

Comment: "Am I correct in assuming that in propositional statements like this, x and y have to be different?" NO. Thus, for $x=0$ we have that $y=0$ satisfies the equation $2x-y=0$.

Comment: Thanks, saved my day!

Comment: Ill check if I can find a reference to write a neat self answer

Comment: No kidding, i went through several lectures and also a whole chapter on this topic, nowhere it was mentioned. It made me think that x and y have to be different if quantifiers are there 

Comment: @senseiwu Food for thought: in the sentence $∀x P(x){\implies}∀x Q(x),$ is there 1 variable, 2 distinct variables that cannot refer to the same object, or 2 variables that can refer to the same object?  P.S. Type `@user` to notify them of comments

Comment: @ryang In a strict sense, I see only 1 variable. But they *can* refer to the same object in the domain of discourse. Please correct me where my thinking is flawed!

Comment: @senseiwu In an even stricter sense, many logic systems consider $∀x P(x){\implies}∀x Q(x)$ to be malformed, and will insist that it be rewritten as $∀x P(x){\implies}∀y Q(y);$ and yes, as in your main question, these two variables indeed can refer to the same object.

Comment: @ryang Found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8588/predicate-logic-two-variables-same-value-allowed) which I believe makes my question a duplicate. The statement in the answer _"For every " means for every , period. So, yes, there are no restrictions on  not being equal to ; any such restrictions would have to be given as predicates (a clause ≠)._ answers my question. The order of quantifiers are reversed there, but I think the idea is the same. So delete or keep mine?